# TextField validation to check if url is correct

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a textfield where it is needed to check if url is from googledrive. How to do that validation?

In this code nothing happens, i dont know why

Comment: Please add the code what have you tried so far?

Comment: I added above. What do I need to change to make it correct?

Comment: nvm I wrapped with form, added key and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `validator` property

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: (value)=>RegExp(r"^(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?drive.google\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;\=]*)?)").hasMatch(value)?null:'Not a valid google drive url'
)
```

Validator returns a String. If you return null, it means that this field's value is correct. I you return any String, this text will be showed as an error below the TextFormField itself

Comment: do I have to wrap it with form? it was working for me once when I just copied and now it is not

Comment: Add your code here!!

Comment: @Theepag who are you to use the '!' to me?

Comment: you could set the autoValidateMode property to *always*